# Appending Strings Using Pointers In C

Tags: c, string, pointers, append

For the life of my I cannot figure out why this program is not working. I'm trying to concatenate two strings using pointers and keep receiving this error:

```
a.out(28095) malloc: *** error 
for object 0x101d36e9c: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

My str_append.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stringlibrary.h"  /* Include the header (not strictly necessary here) */

//appends s to d
void str_append(char *d, char *s){
  int i=0, j=0;

  d = realloc(d, strlength(d)+strlength(s)+1);
  //find the end of d
  while(*(d+i)!='\0'){
    i++;
  }


  //append s to d
  while(*(s+j)!='\0'){
    *(d+i)=*(s+j);
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  *(d+i)='\0';


}
```

I have my own strlength function which I'm 100% sure works.

My main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stringlibrary.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 char* str = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
 str = "Hello";
 char* str2 = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char)); 
str2 = " World";

str_append(str, str2);


 printf("Original String: %d\n", strlength(str));
 printf("Appended String: %d\n", strlength(str));


return 0;
}
```

I've tried reallocating to a temporary variable and receive the same error. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks for all the answers. This site is awesome. Not only do I know where I went wrong (simple mistake I guess), but I found a pretty big hole in what I didn't know about strings. Since I can't use the strcpy function I've implemented my own. It's the source code for strcpy basically.

```
char *string_copy(char *dest, const char *src)
{
 char *result = dest;
 while (*dest++ = *src++);
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
str = "Hello";
```

First you allocate space for 1000 chars and point your pointer to the beginning of that memory.
Then in the second line you point your pointer to a string literal causing a memory leak. 
You pointer no longer points to the allocated memory.
And later in your function you try to change the string literal which is read-only.

Comment: After malloc-ing memory for the string pointer, to assign it some data you might want to do something like strcpy(str, "Hello");

Comment: @TheCodeArtist and Armin Thank you! Wow, my C skills are not up to snuff I guess. How could I go about assigning a string to the allocated memory without using strcpy? This is an assignment and I'm not allowed to use the string.h library.

Comment: Would I create a new pointer that points to the beginning of the string literal and then loop the new pointer into the allocated memory for the str pointer?

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to realloc a pointer to a static variable. When you set

`str = "Hello";`

You're statically assigning that variable (i.e. it will be assigned at compile time). It is then *not* a valid pointer to use for other purposes, including `realloc`. You're also wasting all of the space you retrieved with `malloc` on the line above by throwing away your only pointer to that memory.

What you need to do instead is to use `strcpy` to assign the value:

`strcpy(str, "Hello");`

Then you still have a dynamically allocated pointer, which you can use for `realloc`.

Comment: Thank you. I mistakenly thought I was assigning the string literal to the allocated memory. I blame my sole experience with Java coding and limited knowledge with C. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
str = "Hello";
```

should be:

```
char* str = malloc (1000);
strcpy (str, "Hello");
```

The former allocates some memory and stores the address of that memory into the `str` pointer, then *changes* the `str` pointer to point to *different* (unmalloced) memory.

That's why you're seeing `pointer being realloc'd was not allocated`.

The latter code segment leaves `str` pointing at the malloced memory and just copies the string into that memory.

---

And, as an aside, you should never cast the return value from `malloc` in C - it can hide certain subtle errors and it's unnecessary since C is perfectly capable of implicitly casting the `void*` returned into any other pointer type.

Also, since `sizeof(char)` is always one, you never need to multiply by it. It usually clutters the code unnecessarily.

Lastly, though probably not too important in this case, the C standard reserves identifiers beginning with `str`, `mem` and `wcs` (each followed by a lowercase letter) for future library directions, so you may want to reconsider your use of things like `strlength()` if you want future portability.

Comment: Thank you. There is a lot I need to learn and you've really help expand upon some things I haven't quite figured out yet. Would I use a loop that pointed to the beginning of the string literal to copy it into the mallocated memory?

Comment: @user2066723, I would just use `strcpy` myself but, if you're not able to use those function (eg, homework assignment), you would loop character by character, same as you have in `str_append`.

Answer (score 1):

strings literals (ex : `"MAMA" "MEME"`) are immutable. you cant reallocate them, however, if you use pointer of chars (ex. `char * s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * LEN`) and allocate them then they are mutable.

here :

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
str = "Hello"; //no error BUT wasted memory and cant be reallocated anymore (literal)
```

you should use built-in functions in string manipulation...